# if($totalProducts>0){ $data['success']=true; wp_send_json_success($data);

Tags: php

I get error memory ran out 10240M on points to this.This is plugin to update to google feed.

```
if($totalProducts>0){
    $data['success']=true;
    wp_send_json_success($data);
}else{
    $data['success']=false;
    wp_send_json_error($data);
}

wp_die();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If your server permits to overwrite php.ini settings, you can try this command to increment the memory available for your request:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','16M'); // increment to 16 megabytes of memory
```